# How to present new controller in a xib file swift in another storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xib

I want to present a controller to xib file in another storyboard
In the meantime, I want to use this xib to use several other storyboard
How do i do this?

Comment: Try this :

let newViewController = NewViewController(nibName: "NewViewController", bundle: nil)

// Present View "Modally"
self.presentViewController(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: It sounds like you're asking two different questions: How do I present a controller from a nib file?  How do I present a controller from a specific storyboard?  It would help if you: clarified your question, asked only one question, and gave some idea about what you've tried so far.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Please follow this step.**

1. Register Nib 
   `let xibController = NewViewController(nibName: "XIBController", bundle: nil)`
2. Present View **Modally**
   `self.presentViewController(xibController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Although there is nothing technically wrong in what you've written, it's not actually helpful as it's unclear what the question is actually asking? You are assuming the name of his nib file. You are also assuming the vc is to be presented modally. It's usually a better answer if it answers a specific question, rather than a list of possible suggestions.